# How to implement wordpress blog and magento blog parallely

Tags: wordpress, magento, blogs, fishpig

I have a single instance of Magento running. I am using wordpress blog in magento and want to use magento "Blog" parallely. When i use both blogs magento blog overrides wordpress blog section. Can anyone tell me how we can solve this problem.

You can see the link http://dev.dynatrac.org/ where i want to use this section.

Thanks

Comment: I can't see this is a problem; Magento & WordPress are separate systems. Your question should be: how to read WordPress blog entries in other sites (Hint: XMLRPC)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i repeat my confusion again, i have an magento site http://dev.dynatrac.org/ where client want three section "blog,event,Testimonials". i already use "Fishpig" to implement wordpress in magento site. I also read that magento have its own "Blog" functionality. When i use magento default blog functionality then Fishpig functionality stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using URL http://dev.dynatrac.org/index.php/blog.html, you can use http://dev.dynatrac.org/blog/ and put the wordpress installation in the blog directory of your magento root.

Now using .htaccess or nginx conf (depending upon whether you use apache or nginx) you can redirect the URLs in the form of http://dev.dynatrac.org/blog/something_something.html to blog/ directory.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got that i have to create different wordpress site and implement "Blog,events" in its admin . one last confusion, suppose i create an blog in worpress  admin and create custom post for events. how i can show blog title on home page of magento site.

Comment: Magento Home page is a CMS page. You can just edit the HTML to show blog title/links there.

Comment: We already use wordpress functions but it doesn't pick wordpress functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the AW_Blog extension uses 'blog' as it's router frontName. This overrides the Magento WordPress Integration extension, making the 2 incompatible. In an ideal world, AheadWorks would modify their extension to use a different router frontName (eg. aw_blog) and then would display the blog using a dynamic route (in the same way that Magento WordPress Integration does), thus allowing both extensions to function at the same time.

My advice would be to remove AW_Blog and instead, make use of the [Custom Post Types](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/custom-post-types/) add-on and [Root](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/root/).

The Custom Post Types add-on allows you to create custom post types in WordPress and display them on your Magento integrated blog. As an example, lets say you display your standard blog posts at /blog/ but wanted to create a different type of posts (eg. News articles). You could setup a custom post type called 'news'. By default, this would display all of your news posts at /blog/news/. To improve this, you could install Root, which would remove the /blog/ from the URL, meaning your news articles would be available at /news/.

This method allows you to create what appears to be multiple different blogs but is actually a single WordPress blog that makes use of different custom post types. This method will allow you to have as many different post types as you require.

EG.

http://www.yourmagento.com/blog/
http://www.yourmagento.com/news/
http://www.yourmagento.com/recipes/
http://www.yourmagento.com/tutorials/

All of these would be powered from 1 WordPress installation and integrated into Magento.